# Problem with BWidget's MessageDlg

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, aspect-ratio, bwidget, messagedialog

I am trying to use BWidget's MessageDlg. As it follows from the documentation [here](http://tcltk.free.fr/Bwidget/MessageDlg.html), the `-aspect` ratio defines the ratio between the width and height of the message window.

However, seems it has no effect. For this code:

For

```
package require BWidget
MessageDlg .msg -type yesno -icon warning  -message "Some text." -aspect 50
```

and

```
package require BWidget
MessageDlg .msg -type yesno -icon warning  -message "Some text." -aspect 500
```

in both cases i am getting messages windows with the default ratio (which is 150).

I am using BWidget 1.9.4. Is this a known issue for BWidget? Can you suggest a better alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be declared and then just ignored, and has been this way for a long time. Ow! [File a bug report please](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=add&group_id=12883&atid=112883) (and remember to set the Category field to `bwidget`).